# Double side dictionary in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need a double side dictionary in typescript. 
Obtain value using key and obtain key using value

The easiest way is storing both items as keys

```
dict = {"key": "value", "value": "key"}
```

But I was wondering if there is another solution.

Comment: You could make a class and add logic in a `get` method eg. `get = key => this.dict[key] || Object.keys(this.dict).find(res => this.dict[res] === key)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, I'd suggest making a function that turns a regular dictionary into a double-sided dictionary:

```
function doubleDictionary(t) {
    var ret = Object.assign({}, t);
    for (var k in t) {
        ret[t[k]] = k;
    }
    return ret;
}
var foo = doubleDictionary({ a: "b", c: "d" });
console.log(foo.a); // "b"
console.log(foo.b); // "a"
console.log(foo.c); // "d"
console.log(foo.d); // "c"
```

In TypeScript, I'd suggest using the same function... but adding a signature so that callers get a strongly-typed return value, as follows (explanations of type functions are inline):

```
// ObjToKeyValue<T> turns an object type into a union of key/value tuples:
// ObjToKeyValue<{a: string, b: number}> becomes ["a", string] | ["b", number]
type ObjToKeyValue<T> =
  { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T];

// KeyValueToObj<T> turns a union of key/value tuples into an object type:
// KeyValueToObj<["a", string] | ["b", number]> becomes {a: string, b: number}
type KeyValueToObj<KV extends [keyof any, any]> =
  { [K in KV[0]]: KV extends [K, infer V] ? V : never };

// ReverseTuple<KV> swaps the keys and values in a union of key/value tuples:
// ReverseTuple<[1, 2] | [3, 4]> becomes [2, 1] | [4, 3]
type ReverseTuple<KV extends [any, any]> =
  KV extends [any, any] ? [KV[1], KV[0]] : never;

// ReverseObj<T> takes an object type whose properties are valid keys
// and returns a new object type where the keys and values are swapped:
// ReverseObj<{a: "b", c: "d"}> becomes {b: "a", d: "c"}
type ReverseObj<T extends Record<keyof T, keyof any>> =
  KeyValueToObj<ReverseTuple<ObjToKeyValue<T>>>;

// take an object type T and return an object of type T & ReverseObj<T>
// meaning it acts as both a forward and reverse mapping 
function doubleDictionary<
  S extends keyof any, // infer literals for property values if possible
  T extends Record<keyof T, S>
>(t: T) {
  const ret = Object.assign({}, t) as T & ReverseObj<T>; // return type
  for (let k in t) {
    ret[t[k]] = k as any; // need assertion here, compiler can't verify k
  }
  return ret;
}
```

And now we get the same values from before, but they are known at compile time:

```
const foo = doubleDictionary({ a: "b", c: "d" });
// const foo: {a: "b", c: "d"} & {b: "a", d: "c"};
console.log(foo.a); // compiler knows it is "b"
console.log(foo.b); // complier knows it is "a"
console.log(foo.c); // compiler knows it is "d"
console.log(foo.d); // compiler knows it is "c"
```

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ObjToKeyValue%3CT%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20%5BK%2C%20T%5BK%5D%5D%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3B%0D%0Atype%20KeyValueToObj%3CKV%20extends%20%5Bkeyof%20any%2C%20any%5D%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20KV%5B0%5D%5D%3A%20KV%20extends%20%5BK%2C%20infer%20V%5D%20%3F%20V%20%3A%20never%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20ReverseTuple%3CKV%20extends%20%5Bany%2C%20any%5D%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20KV%20extends%20%5Bany%2C%20any%5D%20%3F%20%5BKV%5B1%5D%2C%20KV%5B0%5D%5D%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0Atype%20ReverseObj%3CT%20extends%20Record%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20keyof%20any%3E%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20KeyValueToObj%3CReverseTuple%3CObjToKeyValue%3CT%3E%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doubleDictionary%3C%0D%0A%20%20S%20extends%20keyof%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20Record%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20S%3E%0D%0A%3E(t%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20ret%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20t)%20as%20T%20%26%20ReverseObj%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20for%20(let%20k%20in%20t)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ret%5Bt%5Bk%5D%5D%20%3D%20k%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20return%20ret%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20doubleDictionary(%7B%20a%3A%20%22b%22%2C%20c%3A%20%22d%22%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20const%20foo%3A%20%7Ba%3A%20%22b%22%2C%20c%3A%20%22d%22%7D%20%26%20%7Bb%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20d%3A%20%22c%22%7D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(foo.a)%3B%20%2F%2F%20compiler%20knows%20it%20is%20%22b%22%0D%0Aconsole.log(foo.b)%3B%20%2F%2F%20complier%20knows%20it%20is%20%22a%22%0D%0Aconsole.log(foo.c)%3B%20%2F%2F%20compiler%20knows%20it%20is%20%22d%22%0D%0Aconsole.log(foo.d)%3B%20%2F%2F%20compiler%20knows%20it%20is%20%22c%22%0D%0A)

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Typescript's Enums automatically have [reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) if they are numeric (this is the default).

**Example**:

```
enum Enum {
    A
}
let a = Enum.A;
let nameOfA = Enum[a]; // "A"
```

Other than that, I don't think there is an easier way than what you did.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach:** We could do this a few different ways but this was the cleanest I could come up with in a short amount of time. Using a Proxy, we were able to hook into the native functionality of the Object getter and add some custom functionality.

Usecases:

> 1. Get value based on `key`. If you use the normal `key` look up, it will return the value like normal. `console.log(dict.key) or console.log(dict['key'])`
> 2. If you do not specify a `key` or a value, the Proxy will return the object the way you initialized it as. `console.log(dict)`.
> 3. Get key based on `value`. If you use the `value` as a lookup, it will attempt to find the `key` and when it doesn't find it, it will skip to grabbing all entries of the object. `console.log(dict['value']);` will return `key`
> 4. It supports setting as well. You can reset any value although I was considering making it immutable.

**Beware this isn't a bullet-proof solution, just what you asked for.**

```
class DoubleSidedDictionary {
  constructor(init) {
    return new Proxy(init, {
      get(target, name) {
        if(typeof name !== 'string') {
          return target;
        }
        if(target[name]) {
          return target[name];
        }
        const entries = Object.entries(target);
        const entry = entries.filter(entry => name == entry[1]);
        return entry.length > 0 ? entry[0][0] : undefined;
      }
    });
  }
}

const dict = new DoubleSidedDictionary({"key": "value", "something": "else"});
```

This solution supports stringified versions of all types. Its your job to convert it back into the type it was.